# Copy constructor of BitSet (or other collections) in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to create a new instance of BitSet class from another BitSet object (input).

I expected something like `new BitSet(input)`, but none found. I could get the new instance with map() method as follows, but I don't think this is the best solution.

```
var r = input.map(_ + 0)(BitSet.canBuildFrom)
```

What's the copy constructor of BitSet? What's the general rule for copy constructor in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another with the bitmask of the first:

```
var r = new BitSet(input.toBitMask)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the general rule is to use immutable collections. They are, well, immutable, so you can pass them around freely without taking special care for copying them.

When you need mutable collections, however, copying collections becomes useful. I discovered that using standard `to` method works:

```
scala> mutable.Set(1, 2, 3)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0.to[mutable.Set]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0 eq res1
res2: Boolean = false
```

However, it won't work with `BitSet` because it is not a generic collection, and `to` needs type constructor as its generic parameter. For `BitSet` you can use the method suggested by Lee. BTW, it is intended exactly for `scala.collection.mutable.BitSet`, because `scala.collection.immutable.BitSet` does not contain such constructor (nor does it need it).

Answer (score 1):

The "copy" method on collections is called `clone` (to be consistent with Java style).

```
scala> collection.mutable.BitSet(1,2,3)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0.clone
res1: scala.collection.mutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0 += 4
res2: res0.type = BitSet(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> res1
res40: scala.collection.mutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)
```